# Confusion about changing meaning of arguments and options, is there an official standard definition?

Tags: command-line, gnu, standard

I came across a confusing variation in the understanding what options and arguments are with regard to the syntax of commands.

For instance, I encountered definitions like:

- `command -a -b -c d e f`

  some differ between `-a -b -c`, call them options or switches and `d e f` by calling them arguments.
- `command -a -b -c d e f`

  some, for instance a `bash` manual, call all `-a -b -c d e f` arguments and explains, that all of them are accessible from a script by `$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6` respectively.
- `command -a b=c`

  some call `-a` an option, `b` an argument and `c` the value, but others mix them like in the first two points, in one variety calling all `-a b c` arguments.

Those three versions are only examples for a plethora of different calling varieties, I do not even know how to list them all, but I noticed that for sure there is no fixed naming convention.

Or at least, there is no standardised naming convention I know about, because I came across different random sources, but even among official Linux and GNU affiliated sites or manuals I could met this inconsistency.

Is there a unquestionable official naming scheme I can refer to?

Comment: The second form is 100% correct from its own point of view.  Context is very important.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adapted from [the POSIX standard's "Utility Argument Syntax" section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap12.html):

```
utility_name [-a] [-b] [-c option_argument]
             [-d|-e] [-f[option_argument]] [operand...]
```

The utility in the example is named `utility_name`. It is followed by **options**, **option-arguments**, and **operands**.

The arguments that consist of `-` characters and single letters or digits, such as `a`, are known as *options* (or, historically, *flags*). Certain options are followed by an *option-argument*, as shown with `[-c option_argument]`. The arguments following the last options and option-arguments are named *operands*.

The standard also [defines "argument" as](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_21)

> In the shell command language, a parameter passed to a utility as the equivalent of a single string in the `argv` array created by one of the `exec` functions. An argument is one of the options, option-arguments, or operands following the command name.

---

All things after the `utility_name` on the command line are the utility's *arguments*, and they all show up in the *positional parameters* if it's a shell script.  The terms option, option-argument, and operand are more specific names for these arguments on the command line.

"Flag" and "switch" are common synonyms to "option".

In the case of

```
utility -a b=c
```

- `-a` and `b=c` are arguments,
- `-a` is an option *if* the utility recognises it as such (the `ln` utility has no `-x` option, so `-x` is not an option to `ln`, strictly speaking, and `ln -x` would trigger a diagnostic message),
- `b=c` is an option-argument *if* the `-a` option takes an argument, otherwise it's an operand,
- `b` and `c` are *not* options, option-arguments and not operands in themselves.

As you notice from my text above, working from the *synopsis* of a utility (as given by the manual of the utility) would have been easier than trying to decode a generic command typed on the command line. The manual will clearly state what options takes option-arguments and what arguments are operands etc.

To call `c` a "value" is IMHO perfectly ok.  It's not a something that is standardised, but very few would misunderstand you if you say "*`c` is the value given to `b`*". It would be clear from the context of the utility in question.

For example

```
$ awk -v var="d" '...' data.in
```

Anyone who knows about `awk` would say that `-v var="d"` means "*the `awk` variable `var` is assigned the value `d` on the command line*".